# What is the independent and standalone meaning and origin of phrase "veiled grab"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, phrase-meaning, phrase-origin, origin-unknown

Reading thro' linked articles in Wikipedia, I have found a phrase, the definitive meaning or synonym of which, I haven't found, searching thro' online dictionaries.

Though I am mentioning the example of one such sentence here, where the phrase has been used, I don't want just the implied/in-context meaning, but a complete, self-contained meaning and origin+development of the phrase, as I have asked in question.

[Wikipedia HeForShe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HeForShe):
"Some critics also believe that the campaign sidelines or discriminates against men (some detractors have interpreted "HeForShe" to be a **veiled grab** for female superiority at men's expense disguised as a push for gender equality)."

Comment: Have you looked up 'veiled' and 'grab' in dictionaries?

Comment: ***Veiled grab*** is not a set phrase, it appears to be more a one-off usage. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=veiled+grab&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=

Comment: It's quite a [common expression](https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=off&sxsrf=ALeKk02NKZtqvTOP5vNTZQ7ekefGBryCHw%3A1590948168509&source=hp&ei=SPHTXs6SHPCOlwS22rbYCA&q=%22veiled+grab%22&oq=%22veiled+grab%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoCCAA6BQgAEIMBOgQIABAKOgcIABBGEPkBOgYIABAWEB46BQghEKABUJsIWJoyYNI2aAFwAHgAgAFkiAH5CJIBBDEzLjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjO1r_j197pAhVwx4UKHTatDYsQ4dUDCAk&uact=5).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I know the separate meanings of "veiled"' and "grab" but I have observed and experienced, that many-times, just combining the meanings of two or more separate words and constructing the phrase meaning is not enough to fully understand it.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Note that most of those hits are for "thinly veiled grab", where "thinly veiled" is a common idiom.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thinly+veiled&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthinly%20veiled%3B%2Cc0

Comment: In this case, as a reading of the many examples available will show, a veiled grab is a grab which is veiled.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Though wearing a bride's veil while grabbing something makes little sense.

Comment: "Though wearing a bride's veil while grabbing something makes little sense." - I don't know about that.

Comment: A secret power-play.